# How to scrape tags that appear within a script

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My intention is to scrape the names of the [top-selling products on Ali-Express](https://bestselling.aliexpress.com/en?spm=2114.11010108.21.3.qyEJ5m).

I'm using the Requests library alongside Beautiful Soup to accomplish this.

```
# Remember to import BeautifulSoup, requests and pprint 

url = "https://bestselling.aliexpress.com/en?spm=2114.11010108.21.3.qyEJ5m"
soup = bs(req.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
#pp.pprint(soup) Verify that the page has been found  
all_items = soup.find_all('li',class_= 'top10-item')

pp.pprint(all_items)

#  []
```

However this returns an empty list, indicating that soup_find_all() did not find any tags fitting that criteria.

[Inspect Element in Chrome displays the list items as such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kooQs.png)
.

However in source code (ul class = "top10-items") contains a script, which seems to iterate through each list item (I'm not familiar with HTML).

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="top10-header"><span class="title">TOP SELLING</span> <span class="sub-title">This week's most popular products</span></div>
            <ul class="top10-items loading" id="bestselling-top10">
            </ul>
            <script class="X-template-top10" type="text/mustache-template">
    {{#topList}}
    <li class="top10-item">
        <div class="rank-orders">
            <span class="rank">{{rank}}</span>
            <span class="orders">{{productOrderNum}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="img-wrap">
            <a href="{{productDetailUrl}}" target="_blank">
                <img src="{{productImgUrl}}" alt="{{productName}}">
            </a>
        </div>
        <a class="item-desc" href="{{productDetailUrl}}" target="_blank">{{productName}}</a>
        <p class="item-price">
            <span class="price">US ${{productMinPrice}}</span>
            <span class="uint">/ {{productUnitType}}</span>
        </p>
    </li>
    {{/topList}}</script>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So this probably explains why soup.find_all() doesn't find the "li" tag.

My question is: How can I extract the item names from the script using Beautiful soup?

Comment: You probably want to use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to load the full page, then save `driver.page_source` and parse through the html with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: I'm guessing selenium executes the full script then stores it in the HTML?

Comment: yes, you can use various browsers like Chrome or Firefox or even a headless browser.

Comment: I've gotten it working. Is there anyway I can do this with Selenium without opening a browser session?

Comment: Yes, you could use [`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/) (although it might be better to use the new [headless Chrome](https://intoli.com/blog/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome/))